# Calculating simple probability in R

Tags: r, probability

I have just started with R and am having trouble with how to enter a seemingly very simple probability question in R. The question is:

There is a big court case, and 20% of the adult population believe the accused is innocent prior to jury selection. Assume that the 12 jurors were selected randomly and independently from the population.

- Find the probability that the jury has at least one member who believe in the accused's innocence prior to jury selection (hint: define the binomial (12,.2) random variable X to be the number of jurors believing in the accused's innocence).
- Find the probability that the jury had at least two members who believed in the accused's innocence (hint: `P(X ≥ 2) = 1-P(X ≤ 1)`, and `P(X ≤ 1) = P(X=0) + P(X=1)`).

I know that the `dbinom(1,12,.2)` will give me the probability of exactly one jury member believing in the accused's innocence, but I am unsure what code to enter for "at least," since this is how the question is phrased. I assume once I am able to calculate "at least" for one jury member, the same code will apply for the second question.  The hint for the second question is throwing me off, however.

This is certainly a stupid and simple question, but any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want at least 1, you could just calculate the probability of having none and take the difference to 1:

```
    1-dbinom(0,12,.2)
```

I guess you could think about it, since it is hinted in the second part of the problem. However, in R the function `pbinom` gives the cumulative probability; so the expression:

```
    pbinom(2,12,.2)
```

amounts to the probability of having 0,1 or 2 people believing the innocence. You could get the same result through:

```
   sum(dbinom(0:2,12,.2))
```

Here I'm taking the probability of 0,1 or 2 people and summing them all